# Chrome doesn’t start on Mac OS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock, bug, google

I successfully installed Chrome on my Mac. However, when I'm trying to start it the browser icon just bounces in the dock once and disappears. Reinstalling, rebooting Mac and other options found on forums didn't help at all. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, I've finally found the solution (so I decided to put it as an answer here).

You need to **open Terminal** (*Spotlight search - type "terminal"*) and **run the following command**:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome
```

It **will remove** Chrome user data so use it at your own risk, but at least it helped me to run Chrome on macOS. Other approaches that seemed safer didn't work for me. You need to **back up the Chrome folder** beforehand if you're worried about losing your data.

Comment: Doesn't this remove all your chrome extension data and session tabs? I don't want to do that. I did nothing wrong and Apple released a horrible update that broke Chrome. Why should I have to suffer and lose data?

Comment: @cameronroe you can copy the contents of this folder somewhere else before removing it and then see what you can add back so it won't be broken

Comment: Have you run Chrome earlier?

Comment: You don't need sudo here as everything unde ~ should be owned by the user

Comment: This is the worst answer ever. You should have warned that this is going to delete chrome's data. I ran this command and lost all my bookmarks!

Comment: @MostafaArianNejad Added clarifications to the answer, thanks!

Comment: MacBook Pro 2016 running MacOS Mojave, this worked instantaneously. Did not care about losing data. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

OK. I did not have the Chrome folder under ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google  So I just deleted the "Google" folder under "Application Support" and that fixed it!! deleted the Google folder - re-started Chrome and the Google folder and other folders under it got created

Answer (score 4):

Other thing is to run Chrome from the Terminal.

```
$ cd '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS'
$ ./Google\ Chrome &
```

Comment: [1] 61144
[1]+  Killed: 9               ./Google\ Chrome

Comment: This works for me. Then I can open the Chrome by clicking the app as usual.

Comment: Surprisingly, this... worked :D

Comment: Worked for me as well - thanks.

This seems to occur when I have to force quit Chrome -- it then does not seem to open via Dock, Finder, hyperlink (since its my default browser)

Answer (score 1):

If the above command doesn't work, Open the Spotlight Search (cmd+space), Enter "/Library/Application Support" . Locate the Google folder, Move to Trash. And reinstall Chrome once again

Answer (score 1):

Better solution than removing the folder, since we don't know the impact, it to change folder permission.

Open Terminal and use command below:

```
sudo chown -R $(scutil <<< "show State:/Users/ConsoleUser" | awk '/Name :/ && ! /loginwindow/ { print $3 }') ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google
```

This is basically same solution few other folks are mentioning above, but they are recommending the GUI way.

PS: your password (administrator privilege) will be required.

Comment: My editing solved exactly this problem? Why are you editing it again? If you are currently root in the terminal and enter `$USER` , your user name will not appear but root. So the directory would be changed to root.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved by repairing folder permissions in the `~/Library` folder as follows:

1. Using Finder, navigate to `~/Library` using the `⌘⇧G` (Command+Shift+G) command
2. Open the folder info dialog
3. In the "**Sharing & Permissions**" section, unlock the lock by entering credentials
4. From the cogwheel drop down menu, select the "**Apply to enclosed items...**" action

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7494016
Basically you need to give the Google folder admin privleges in the Application Support folder. Like this:

1. Open a finder window or click on the Desktop.
2. Hold down SHIFT+COMMAND+G (⇧⌘G) type "~/Library/Application Support". Then click Go
3. Find the folder named "Google"
4. Get Info (⌘I)
5. In the Get Info window click on the lock in
   bottom right corner Enter your login password (you need to be an
   admin) and press enter
6. Click the + button on bottom left
7. From the drop down click on Administrators Then click on select At the bottom of window you should now see admin Under "Name" To the right of amin click on "read only" and change to Read & Write
8. Now click on the setting cog and select Apply to enclosed like this

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that Google Chrome was in MacOS Login Startup Items. When I closed it, I couldn't restart it for some reason. I removed it from the Startup Items and now all's good.